# WPF icon doesn't show

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

I want to use pathGeometry from my icon.xaml file  my project but WPF does not show how can i use my icons?
Please find my codes and screenshot below.

[image]

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="-1 40 0 20">
    <Button x:Name="btnHome" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnHome_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnHome_MouseLeave" Click="btnHome_Click">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource home}" IconWidth="16" Text="Factory Method" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnDashboard" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnDashboard_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnDashboard_MouseLeave" Click="btnDashboard_Click">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource dashboard}" IconWidth="16" Text="Dashboard" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnProducts" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnProducts_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnProducts_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource products}" IconWidth="16" Text="Products" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnProductStock" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnProductStock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnProductStock_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource car}" IconWidth="16" Text="Product Stock" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOrderList" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnOrderList_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnOrderList_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource email}" IconWidth="16" Text="Order List" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnBilling" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnBilling_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnBilling_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource billing}" IconWidth="16" Text="Billing" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnPointOfSale" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnPointOfSale_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnPointOfSale_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource car}" IconWidth="16" Text="Point Of Sale" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSecurity" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnSecurity_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnSecurity_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource lock}" IconWidth="16" Text="Security" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSetting" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnSetting_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnSetting_MouseLeave">
        <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource settings}" IconWidth="16" Text="Setting" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You've not included enough information to answer your question.  There's lots of extraneous markup and none of the resources you're trying to show. But your problem is likely to be that those resources aren't something can be rendered as an icon or you forgot a fill brush.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded you icon.xaml in Application Resources?

Like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="icon.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I added that before 


`<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DarkTheme.xaml"/>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Icons.xaml"/>

                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/MainStyle.xaml"/>
                
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
`

Comment: If you have this in app resources then use StaticResource instead of DynamicResource.